# How to zip multiple but an unknown number of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have multiple lists and I want to zip them like shown in the following example :

```
d = {}
clients = ["client_1","client_2","client_3",...] # n number of client

# every client has a list of element :
d["acc_list" + client] = [1, 2, 3, ...]
```

So how could I zip them without knowing the number of clients :

```
acc_clients = zip(d["acc_list" + "client_0"],d["acc_list" + "client_2"],d["acc_list" + "client_3"], .... )
```

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: `len(clients)`?

Comment: I want to zip n number of lists, so instead of doing : 
`zip(d["acc_list" + "client_1"],d["acc_list" + "client_2"],d["acc_list" + "client_3"] )`  
 I want an efficient way to loop through clients list

Comment: like something like that :                                                

 `acc_clients = zip(d["acc_list" + client ] for client in client_names)` but it doesnt work

Comment: Please provide a [mre] *in your question* and explain *how* it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you already have the `client` part in `client_names`, so you can make a list of them:

```
client_d = [d["acc_list" + client ] for client in client_names]
```

Now to `zip` them together you can apply to `*` operator to the list:

```
acc_clients = zip(*[d["acc_list" + client ] for client in client_names])
```

or as @wwii points out, we don't need to get a `list comprehension` to iterate over `client_names` first and then let `*` iterate over the result, we can make a generator expression:

```
acc_clients = zip(*(d["acc_list" + client ] for client in client_names))
```

Comment: ...`zip(*(d["acc_list" + client ] for client in clients))`